# Apk won't start of a certain project in Godot

Tags: android, terminal, apk, updates, godot

I have a game which I have already exported for windows in Godot 3.2.2.stable. I also published it.

But I am not able to publish it for android.

I also reinstalled SDK, export template, jarsigner and Keystore but it didn't work.

I tried to export a demo project which worked nicely.

But this game is not working.

There was also no error in the terminal window in Godot. I also matched the Keystore with the demo.

This project is an update of my 1st published game. Can anyone solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Forgot to remove Admob directory from the modules list but deleted AdMob. It's working now.